# Configuring gateway for two interfaces

Tags: network-interface, gateway

I have a CentOS machine with two network interfaces, one that I want connected to the internet and one that I want connected to an internal network.

I am trying to make both interfaces work, but I can't figure out what gateway I need to have them both work.

This is the current output of route:

```
Destination      Gateway      Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0      *            255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.60.0      *            255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
link-local       *            255.255.255.0   U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local       *            255.255.255.0   U     1003   0        0 eth1
default          172.16.0.2   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

These are the configuration files for the interfaces:

```
ifcfg-eth0  DEVICE=eth0
            HWADDR=08:00:27:8c:56:66
            TYPE=Ethernet
            UUID=d4a727c9-a520-4605-a53b-f1d23bff69aa
            ONBOOT=yes
            MM_CONTROLLED=yes
            BOOTPROTO=dhcp

ifcfg-eth1  TYPE=Ethernet
            BOOTPROTO=static
            NAME=eth1
            DEVICE=eth1
            HWADDR=08:00:27:8B:A6:25
            ONBOOT=yes
            NETMASK=255.255.255.0
            NETWORK=172.16.60.0
            IPADDR=172.16.60.1
            BROADCAST=172.16.60.255
            GATEWAY=172.16.60.2
```

I can access the network attached to eth1 but I cannot access the internet. If I remove eth1 and set the default gateway as 192.168.0.1, I can access the internet.

How should I configure the interfaces?

Comment: If the proper gateway is `192.168.0.1`, I don't see how setting `GATEWAY=172.16.60.2` helps that.

Comment: Without that I cannot access the network connected to eth1

Comment: Thanks! I have removed the GATEWAY=172.16.60.2 and used static routes.